# GROUP BY value1 and select row with highest of value2 within the group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table called `values` in a `MySQL 5.7` database:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 7 | something4 |
| foo | 5 | something1 |
| foo | 12 | anything3 |
| bar | 3 | something7 |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| bar | 0 | anything8 |
| baz | 99 | anything9 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

I want to `GROUP BY value1` and always keep the row with the highest value in `value2`.

So the expected result of the table above is:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 12 | anything3 |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

How can I do that with `SQL`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to *group*.  You want to filter!  You are keeping the original rows.

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select v.*
from values v
where v.value2 = (select max(v2.value2)
                  from values v2
                  where v2.value1 = v.value1
                 );
```

Comment: Is `from t t2 where` a typo?

Comment: @David . . . But I see you included a table name in the question, so I used it in the answer.  Note that `values` is a poor choice for a table name because it is a SQL keyword (think `insert`).

Answer (score 1):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable (value1 varchar(50),  value2   int, value3 varchar(50));

 insert into mytable values('foo',  7,  'something4');
 insert into mytable values('foo',  5,  'something1');
 insert into mytable values('foo',  12, 'anything3');
 insert into mytable values('bar',  3,  'something7');
 insert into mytable values('bar',  18, 'anything5');
 insert into mytable values('bar',  12, 'anything8');
 insert into mytable values('baz',  99, 'anything9');
 insert into mytable values('baz',  100,    'something0');
```

Query#1 (using inner join)

```
 select m.* from mytable m inner join 
 (select value1, max(value2) maxvalue2 from mytable group by value1) m2
 on m.value1=m2.value1 and m.value2=m2.maxvalue2
```

Output:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 12 | anything3 |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

Query#2 (using subquery in where clause)

```
 select m.*
 from mytable m
 where m.value2 = (select max(m2.value2) from mytable  m2 where m2.value1 = m.value1);
```

Output:

| value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 12 | anything3 |
| bar | 18 | anything5 |
| baz | 100 | something0 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=70be6f4d8f05e13338da00eb9463d9ef)*